# How can I make the label of a checkbox clickable in knockout js?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

How can we make the text clickable. Below is a list which is referred to a knockout template. I can directly check the box, but cannot able to make the text clickable so that it can reflect the checkbox. 
HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'choiceTmpl', foreach: choices, templateOptions: { selections: selectedChoices } }"></ul>

    <script id="choiceTmpl" type="text/html">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: $item.selections" />
            <label data-bind="text: $data"></label>
        </li>
    </script>
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = {
    choices: ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
    selectedChoices: ko.observableArray(["two", "four"])
};

viewModel.selectedChoicesDelimited = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    return this.selectedChoices().join(",");
}, viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Jsfiddle Demo: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Jm2Mh/)

Is there any way, that we can make it clickable?

Comment: Have you tried giving the checkbox and label same ID?

Answer (score 3):

Put a `<label>` around the `<input>` element:

```js
var viewModel = {
  choices: ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
  selectedChoices: ko.observableArray(["two", "four"])
};

viewModel.selectedChoicesDelimited = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
  return this.selectedChoices().join(",");
}, viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: choices">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input data-bind="attr: { 
                          value: $data 
                        }, 
                        checked: $parent.selectedChoices" type="checkbox" />
      
      <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<pre data-bind="html: JSON.stringify(selectedChoices(), null, 2)"></pre>
```

In your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x0f1pk6q/

Alternatively, you could construct an `id` attribute in the loop. You'll have to *make absolutely sure it's unique though*. I'd advice you to use some sort of utility that increments an index in a closure that is guaranteed to be unique per session.

You need to link the `id` and `for` attributes using the same method:

```js
var viewModel = {
  choices: ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
  selectedChoices: ko.observableArray(["two", "four"]),
  getCbId: function(val, i) {
    // This combination of value and index aims to create a 
    // "kind-of-unique" id. See answer for more info.
    return "CB_" + val + "_" + i; 
  }
};

viewModel.selectedChoicesDelimited = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
  return this.selectedChoices().join(",");
}, viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: choices">
  <li>
    
    <input data-bind="attr: { 
                        value: $data, 
                        id: $root.getCbId($data, $index())  
                      }, 
                      checked: $root.selectedChoices" type="checkbox" />
    
    <label data-bind="text: $data, 
                      attr: { 
                        for: $root.getCbId($data, $index()) 
                      }"></label>
    
  </li>
</ul>

<pre data-bind="html: JSON.stringify(selectedChoices(), null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: Is there a way without wrapping the input with the label? That's not always desirable...

Comment: @cale_b, I've added an example that uses an `id` and `for` attribute. Personally, I prefer the wrapped version. If you're not careful, you could end up with duplicate id's... The wrapped version doesn't have that risk.